# unexpected exception thrown for file open/close status

Tags: c++

Hi I have sample of code

```
try {
ifs.open(sourceHtmlFile.c_str());
std::cout << ifs << "\n" ;
if( !ifs ) ;
throw std::string("Could not open file");
} catch (std::string &ex) {
std::cout << ex << " !\n";
}
```

o/p

when file do not exist:
ifs - > 0
throws exception expected

when file do exist
ifs -> 0xbfc885b4
still it throws exception.

I want to know why its throwing exception in both cases

Thanks,

Comment: Offtopic because you could have easily found the error yourself if you had fixed your indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `;` after the `if` condition. This semicolon terminates the conditional statement, so your `throw` is always executed.